# CakePHP 3 - How to match on indirect associations?

Tags: php, cakephp, entity-relationship, query-builder, cakephp-3.0

So my models work like this:

- `User` has one `Investor`
- `Investor` has many `Investments`
- `Investments` has many `Bids`
- `Bids` belogs to `ObjectInAuction`
- `ObjectInAuction` has many `Bids`

I need to build a function in `ObjectInAuction` that returns all the `ObjectInAuction` entities that have been invested by the `User` with some `$user_id`.

This is what I have in `ObjectsInAuctionTable.php`:

```
public function getAuctionObjectsInvestedBy($user_id)
{
    $query = $this->find();
    $query->contain([
        'Bids.Investments.Investors' => function ($q) use ($user_id) {
             return $q->where(['Investors.user_id' => $user_id]);
         }
    ]);
}
$invoices = $query->all();
```

The problem is that this is returning all invoices in the database, every time. How can I make this work?

Comment: Thank you it is a duplicate